# Splitting a string in JavaScript by multiple delimeters

Tags: javascript

I want to split a string :

```
OU(EGAL([Zone_libre_utilisateur],"0000"),ET([Code_courrier],"ABO"))
```

using delimeter `,` & `(` in javascript. How can it be done?

Comment: What output do you expect for this example?

Comment: @galambalazs Looking at the string, I believe he meant to split only at `,` and `(`

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regex to split:

```
var str = 'OU(EGAL([Zone_libre_utilisateur],"0000"),ET([Code_courrier],"ABO"))';
var a = str.split(/[,(]/);
console.log(a);
//["OU", "EGAL", "[Zone_libre_utilisateur]", ""0000")", "ET", "[Code_courrier]", ""ABO"))"]
```

Or even better (depending on your requirement):

```
var str = 'OU(EGAL([Zone_libre_utilisateur],"0000"),ET([Code_courrier],"ABO"))';
var a = str.split(/[,()[\]"]+/);
console.log(a);
//["OU", "EGAL", "Zone_libre_utilisateur", "0000", "ET", "Code_courrier", "ABO", ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var splitString = originalString.split(/[,(]/);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace all the ( characters with , and then use the split method...

e.g. something like...

```
string.replace('(',',').split(',')
```